How to loop through child components in Blazor
I have created a custom textbox component based on a simple  element that implements an IOldValue interface.  The interface has a function called SetOldValue() that saves the current value to an OldValue variable when called.  I want to call a function SetAllOldValues() in the parent component that iterates through only the immediate child components that implement the IOldValue interface and call the SetOldValue function on each.  This is instead of creating a variable for each element and calling the function as that would be cumbersome for busy pages. Something like this pseudocode:
foreach (var control in this.Controls.OfType<IOldValue>())
{
    control.SetOldValue();
}

Here's the custom textbox
@implements IOldValue

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

<input @bind="Value" @bind:event="oninput" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<object> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = e.Value!.ToString()!;
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }

    public object OldValue { get; set; }
    public object CurrentValue
    {
        get { return _currentValue; }
    }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; } // Ignore
    public bool HasChanges { get; set; } // Ignore

    private string _currentValue;

    public string ReportDifs()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public void SetOldValue()
    {
        OldValue = Value;
    }
}

Interface:
namespace WebUI.Components.Controls;

public interface IOldValue
{
  object OldValue { get; set; }

  object CurrentValue { get; }

  string FriendlyName { get; set; }

  bool HasChanges { get; set; }

  string ReportDifs();

  void SetOldValue();
}

The parent page
<br />

<div class="container col-12">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Prefix</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <MyTextBox @ref="@_prefix" @bind-Value="@_person.Prefix" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <MyTextBox @ref="@_firstName" @bind-Value="@_person.FirstName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Middle Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <MyTextBox @ref="@_middleName" @bind-Value="@_person.MiddleName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <MyTextBox @ref="@_lastName" @bind-Value="@_person.LastName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <label>Suffix</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <MyTextBox @ref="@_suffix" @bind-Value="@_person.Suffix" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @onclick="ButtonClicked">Set Old Values</button>

@code {

    private MyTextBox _prefix = new();
    private MyTextBox _firstName = new();
    private MyTextBox _middleName = new();
    private MyTextBox _lastName = new();
    private MyTextBox _suffix = new();

    private Person _person = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _person = new Person
            {
                Prefix = "Mr.",
                FirstName = "John",
                MiddleName = "Q",
                LastName = "Public",
                Suffix = "Sr."
            };

        //SetAllOldValues();
    }

    private void ButtonClicked(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetAllOldValues();
    }

    private void SetAllOldValues()
    {
        // Pseudocode - will not work as is.
        // This logic is what is needed.
        // foreach (var control in this.Controls.OfType<IOldValue>())
        // {
        //     control.SetOldValue();
        // }

        // Will work, but cumbersome
        _prefix.SetOldValue();
        _firstName.SetOldValue();
        _middleName.SetOldValue();
        _lastName.SetOldValue();
        _suffix.SetOldValue();
    }

    private class Person
    {
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
    }
}


This looks like code to track the state of an edit context and the ability to do a reset on that context.  Your component looks remarkably similar to stuff I wrote in my early Blazor days.   If so, there are more elegant ways I can suggest.

Value = e.Value!.ToString()!; is the wrong thing to do. See Avoid overwriting parameters in ASP.NET Core Blazor

Thanks to all for your input.  I'm not using an edit context here.  I should have mentioned before that the data for my particular model has around 40 fields spread across many components in many accordion items.   Can't change that.  The SetOldValues() method can be called from any one of these sub/child components and cascade downwards.  Also, they need to be called from that level, not a callback to the top level to reset everything.  There are good suggestions here and I think I can combine them.  I'll update soon.  If anyone has other suggestions, please do!

Here's an answer that uses .ForEach from List type.
private MyTextBox _prefix = new();
private MyTextBox _firstName = new();
private MyTextBox _middleName = new();
private MyTextBox _lastName = new();
private MyTextBox _suffix = new();
private List<MyTextBox> _textBoxes = default!;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   _textBoxes = new() { _prefix, _firstName, _middleName, _lastName, _suffix };

   _textBoxes.ForEach(t => t.SetOldValue());
}

Interesting question-- I hope someone suggests an answer that uses system.reflection

trying to avoid having variables for each one.  The programmer would have to know which components implemented the IOldValue interface.  And I have other controls like dropdown, checkbox, etc that would be included in the loop too.  Thank you, though.  I'm also hoping for a reflection based answer.  Should add my goal is to save initial values so I can compare/reset without a db call.  I would not save to old value on every change.

To solve your problem you need to cascade a registration delegate into the edit form.  Each custom control registers itself with the parent through the cascade.  You now have a collection of IOldValue components you can iterate and call methods on.
However, it's ugly, and requires custom edit components to work.  Consider rethinking your approach.  Move the tracking into a separate object.
This example code is based on a simple Country object:
    public record DboCountry
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; init; }
        public string Name { get; init; } = string.Empty;
        public string Code { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    }

Editing is through a record edit object created from the base record.
public class CountryEditContext
{
    private DboCountry _baseRecord;
    public Guid Uid { get; private set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [TrackState] public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [TrackState] public string Code { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public CountryEditContext(DboCountry record)
    {
        _baseRecord = record;
        this.Load(record);
    }

    public void Load(DboCountry record) 
    {
        _baseRecord = record;
        this.Uid= record.Uid;
        this.Name= record.Name;
        this.Code= record.Code;
    }

    public DboCountry AsRecord
        => new DboCountry
        {
            Uid= this.Uid,
            Name= this.Name,
            Code= this.Code,
        };

    public void Reset()
        => this.Load(_baseRecord);
}

You edit model is the CountryEditContext instance.  The standard edit controls also point to the properties in the CountryEditContext instance.
Now calling Reset on the CountryEditContext instance resets all the controls.
The full code including the BlazrEditStateTracker, integration with validation and NavigationLock is here  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.EditForm
The full edit form looks like this:
@page "/"
@inject CountryEditorPresenter Presenter
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject IJSRuntime Js
@implements IDisposable

@if (_editContext is null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Loading</div>
}
else
{
    <PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
    <EditForm EditContext=_editContext>
        <FluentValidationValidator DisableAssemblyScanning="@true" />
        <BlazrEditStateTracker />
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label class="form-label">Country</label>
            <BlazrInputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="this.Presenter.Record.Name" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => this.Presenter.Record.Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label class="form-label">Code</label>
            <BlazrInputText class="form-control" @bind-Value=this.Presenter.Record.Code />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => this.Presenter.Record.Code" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2 text-end">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" hidden="@_isClean" @onclick="this.Reset">Reset</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="@_isClean" @onclick="this.Save">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" hidden="@_isClean" @onclick="this.ExitWithoutSave">Exit Without Saving</button>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" hidden="@_isDirty" @onclick="this.Exit">Exit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <ValidationSummary />
        </div>
    </EditForm>

    <NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="_isDirty" />
}

@code {
    private EditContext _editContext = default!;
    private IDisposable? _navLockerDispose;
    private BlazrEditStateStore? _editStateStore => _editContext?.GetStateStore();
    private bool _isDirty => _editStateStore?.IsDirty() ?? false;
    private bool _isClean => !_isDirty;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Presenter.GetItemAsync(Guid.NewGuid());
        _editContext = new EditContext(Presenter.Record);
        _navLockerDispose = NavManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(this.OnLocationChanging);
    }

    private ValueTask OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        // Prevent navigation if the edit context is dirty
        if (_isDirty)
            context.PreventNavigation();

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Save()
    {
        if (_isClean)
            return;

        // Validate the form
        if (_editContext?.Validate() ?? false)
        {
            await this.Presenter.SaveItemAsync();
            // mock an async call to the data pipeline to save the record
            var updatedRecord = this.Presenter.Record.AsRecord;
            await Task.Delay(100);
            // Error handling code here

            // This will reset the edit context and the EditStateTracker
            _editContext = new EditContext(this.Presenter.Record);
        }

    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        if (_isClean)
            return;

        this.Presenter.Reset();
            _editStateStore?.Reset();
    }

    private void Exit()
    {
        // Belt and braces check before exiting
        if (_isClean)
            this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }

    private async Task ExitWithoutSave()
    {
        // Confirm with a Js Confirm popup
        bool confirmed = await Js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure you want to exit without saving?");

        if (confirmed)
        {
            // Reset the EditStateStore - it will now be clean, so we can exit
            _editStateStore?.Reset();
            this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => _navLockerDispose?.Dispose();
}

And the broker:
public class CountryEditorPresenter
{
    private ICountryDataBroker _broker;

    public CountryEditContext Record { get; private set; } = new(new());

    public CountryEditorPresenter(ICountryDataBroker broker)
        => _broker = broker;

    public async ValueTask<bool> GetItemAsync(Guid uid)
    {
        var record = await _broker.GetItemAsync(uid);

        //Logic to check we got a record

        // Create a new record edit context
        this.Record = new(record);
        
        return true;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> SaveItemAsync()
    {
        // Get the record to save
        var saveRecord = this.Record.AsRecord;
        await _broker.SaveItemAsync(saveRecord);

        // Create a new record edit context
        this.Record = new(saveRecord);

        return true;
    }

    public void Reset()
        => this.Record.Reset();
}


I think if you think bottom-up instead of top-down, this task might look simpler.  Cascade or pass the parent to the child, and let the child register itself by calling a method in the parent.  In this way, you should be able to add any number of Child objects, even dynamically, without adding any kind of tracking logic.
Parent.razor
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <Child />
    <Child />
</CascadingValue>
<button @onclick=SetOldValues>Save</button>

@code {
    private List<Child> _registeredChildren = new ();

    public void RegisterChild(Child child)
    {
        _registeredChildren.Add(child);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    public void SetOldValues(){
        foreach (var child in _registeredChildren) child.SetOldValue();
    }
}

Child.razor
   @code{
        [CascadingParameter]
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
        public void SetOldValue(){
             // Your business logic here.
        }
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            Parent?.RegisterChild(this);  // Register this child with the parent
        }
    }

